# string concatenation multiple variable by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a line of string:

```
apple:{0},pear:{1},banana:{2}
```

I want to raw the variable to the string. Here is my code:

```
var AllString="apple:{0},pear:{1},banana:{2}";
var apple=0;
var pear=1;
var banana=2;
var NewString=AllString.replace("{0}",apple).replace("{1}",pear).replace("{2}",banana);
```

In spite it works, it is so troublesome.

I have learned C# before, and C# has a syntax sugar just like this:

```
var NewString=string.format(AllString,apple,pear,banana);
```

I am not sure but are there any similarities like this in jquery to make it more convenient? Thank you.

Comment: is it like replacing the curly braces ?

Comment: `AllString.replace(/[{}]/g, "");` ?

Comment: Let's not mark it as a duplicate, but you should check all answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format).

Comment: @skobaljic That's what I need, thank you.

Comment: @skobaljic why not mark as duplicate?  It seems a perfect example